# Show MsgBox() data from two arrays in a loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write code to show data from two arrays via a MsgBox(). I have the code below, but of course it doesn't work:

```
Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 4, 7}
Dim letters() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}
' Iterate through the list by using nested loops.
For Each number As Integer In numbers and For Each letter As String In letters
   MsgBox(number.ToString & letter & " ")
Next
```

What do I need to do to get output that looks like this? :

> 1a
>   4b
>   7c

Comment: `For Each` is the wrong thing to use. An ordinary `For` loop will work. Also, you do not want nested loops.

Comment: Do you want a message box for each iteration, or a single message box at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `For` loop that uses an index rather than a `For Each` loop:

```
Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 4, 7}
Dim letters() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}

For i As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
   MsgBox(numbers(i) & letters(i))
Next
```

You can also use the [Zip() linq operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
For Each output As String In numbers.Zip(letters, Function(n, l) n & l)
    MsgBox(output)
Next
```

Comment: You don't actually need to call .`ToString()` when using the `&` operator as the operator does it for you. Although it looks *wrong*.

Comment: Good point. I forget the operator must be defined separately for the `int` type, which would of course be able to call ToString() if needed.

Comment: I would *feel* better with `$"{numbers(i)}{letters(i)}"`, `$"{n}{l}"`

Comment: @djv That always seems to reveal that an OP is using VS2015 :(

Comment: string interpolation would be much slower here for not really any code saving, since there's a separate step to parse the format string and the concatenation expression is small.

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from something like a dictionary.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish combining 2 arrays arbitrarily but something like this may be better:

```
Dim Dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From {{1, "a"}, {4, "b"}, {7, "c"}}

    For Each Item In Dict
        MsgBox(Item.Key & Item.Value)
    Next
```

That would allow you to lookup items based on the ID (integer) with Linq such as:

Dict.Where(Function(x) x.Key = 1).SingleOrDefault and grab the key/value pair.